# getting frequent Detected PID change - Mongo client should have been reconnected with rails mongoid app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

When running a Rails application, I am getting frequent mongo errors:

```
W, [2023-04-15T04:40:34.178698 #102970]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Detected PID change - Mongo client should have been reconnected (old pid 100659, new pid 102970
W, [2023-04-15T04:40:34.181347 #102970]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Detected PID change - Mongo client should have been reconnected (old pid 100659, new pid 102970
W, [2023-04-15T04:40:34.181566 #102970]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Detected PID change - Mongo client should have been reconnected (old pid 100659, new pid 102970
```

Anyone know what causes this?  Is the timeout set too low somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a forking server in your Rails app. In this case it is necessary to reconnect mongo clients after forking. There are examples how to do it in [Mongoid documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/configuration/#usage-with-forking-servers)